# Update DataGridView or update the binded DataSource?

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, datagridview

I am working on a `C#` project in which a `DataGridView` is shown in the `WinForm` at runtime and needs to be updated every 2~3 seconds. The `DataSrouce` of each `DataGridView` is binding to a `DataSet` which could be changed according to users's operation.

As I am totally a newbie to `C#`, I have no idea how should I achieve a real-time refresh of the forms in the GUI. Of course I need multi-threading so that the update of the data shown could be done in background and the GUI does not hang.

PS: In `Qt`, each `view` is bounded to a `model` and I can update each `model` in a different thread from the main GUI thread so that the GUI will not stuck. This is what I am now doing. Sample codes below.

```
// MainForm.cs
public Bind()
{
   dataGridView.DataSource = TableCollection.DataTable1;
}
public StartTimer()
{
   System.Windows.Forms.Timer tdfTimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
   guiTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(Refresh);
   guiTimer.Interval = 500;
   guiTimer.Start();
}
public void Refresh(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (backgroundwork == null)
   {
      backgroundwork = new BackgroundWorker();
      backgroundwork.DoWork += delegate(object s, DoWorkEventArgs args) { TableCollection.UpdateData(); };
   }
   if (!backgroundwork.IsBusy)
      backgroundwork.RunWorkerAsync();
}

// TableCollection.cs
class TableCollection
{
   static DataTable dataTable1;
   public DataTable1
   {
      get { return dataTable1; }
   }
   static public void UpdateData()
   {
       // here i update each row in dataTable1
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you want to update the datagridview frequently so you have to create BindingSource for that.the code should look like

BindingSource DGSource = new BindingSource(TableCollection.DataTable1, null);
dataGridView2.DataSource = DGSource;